# how to insert table in sqlite from python

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt5

I'm new to python and I'm creating a gui application using pyqt5 with sqlite database.i found that my program could connect databse but it cannot create table and insert records SHOWING 'RESTART SHELL'when i press the button

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import sqlite3

class DBHelper():
    def __init__(self):
        self.book=sqlite3.connect("Books.db")
        self.c=self.book.cursor()
        self.c.execute('''CREATE TABLE lib1(
        book_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT,
        title TEXT,
        author TEXT,
        price INTEGER);''')
        self.c.execute("INSERT INTO lib1(book_id,title,author,price)VALUES(1,'python','allan downey',400);")
        self.c.execute("INSERT INTO lib1(book_id,title,author,price)VALUES(1,'c complete reference','Herbert Schieldt',400);")
        self.c.execute("INSERT INTO lib1(book_id,title,author,price)VALUES(2,'Harry Potter','J.K Rowling',800);")
        self.c.execute("INSERT INTO lib1(book_id,title,author,price)VALUES(3,'Half Girlfriend','chetan bhagath',400);")
        self.c.execute("INSERT INTO lib1(book_id,title,author,price)VALUES(4,'ponniyin selvan','kalki',400);")
    def searchBook(self,title):
        self.c.execute("SELECT price FROM lib1 WHERE title="+str(title))
        self.data=self.c.fetchone()
        if not self.data:
            QMessageBox.warning(QMessageBox(),'ERROR! COULD NOT FIND ANY BOOKK WITH THIS TITLE'+str(title1))
        self.c.close()
        self.book.close()
        return self.data
    def TotalCost(self,quantity):
        self.Total=self.data*self.quantity
        self.c.close()
        self.book.close()
        return self.total



class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.t1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.t1.setObjectName("t1")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.t1)
        self.b1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.b1.setObjectName("b1")
        self.b1.clicked.connect(self.buttonclicked1)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.b1)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.t2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.t2.setObjectName("t2")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.t2)
        self.b2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.b2.setObjectName("b2")
        self.b2.clicked.connect(self.buttonclicked2)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.b2)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3)
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_4)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_4)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "BOOK TITLE:"))
        self.b1.setText(_translate("Form", "FIND PRICE"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Form", "PRICE:"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Form", "QUANTITY:"))
        self.b2.setText(_translate("Form", "TOTAL"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("Form", "TOTAL:"))


    def buttonclicked1(self):
        self.p1=DBHelper()
        self.price=self.t1.text()
        self.p1.searchBook(self.price)

    def buttonclicked2(self):
        self.p2=DBHelper()
        self.total=self.t2.text()
        self.p2.TotalCost(self.total)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Upon running the code I get an error saying "SHOWING RECORDS, RESTART SHELL". Can someone please assist me? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! It seems like you're post is mostly code (that hasn't been formatted correctly - if you need help formatting, [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). You'll need to either add more detail or eliminate the unneccessary code to create a [**minimal**, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Okay first and foremost -- when dealing with the SQLite3 database there should be no mention of pyqt5 or qt in general.  the sqlite3 library is a python library further when dealing with the database (your back-end model) there should be no direct interaction with your GUI (your front-end view).

Comment: Do all your database manipulation using straight python and have your Model pass formatted results to the GUI via your Controller and then when the GUI needs to update the database it passes its information to the Controller which then verifies/translate that into information that the Model can handle easily.  I typically use dictionaries to do this because they make the translation process more generic but that is my preference and whatever structure you choose should just be consistent.

Comment: Note if you need a more generic python database handler I can share with you the template that I use.